# n-Concatenation of a vector of length N (n divides N) without looping (in R)

Tags: r, string-concatenation

Suppose we have a 1D string vector `V` of length `N`, where `N` is a given natural non-zero integer. Let us introduce a number `n`  such that `N%%n==0` (n divides N).

I would like to obtain the vector `U` such that the 1st component is the concatenation of the first `n` components of `V`, the 2nd component is the concatenation of the second `n` components of '''V''', etc., and this **without** using any loop, plus `n` is a variable (basically it is derived in another part of a bigger code).

Thus, given `N`, say `V=as.character(1:N)`. Introduce `n` with `N%%n==0`.
I would like to do **without loop** (also possibly without *if*) and **in one line**:

```
U = c()
if (length(V)/n>1) {
  for (t in 1:(length(V)/n)) {
    U = paste(U, V[ ngroup(1:length(V),n,ifelse(t==n,0,t)) ], sep='')
  }
} else { U=paste(V,collapse='') }
```

where the function `ngroup` simply is given by

```
ngroup <- function(x,n,r) which(x%%n == r) # r: number in [0, 1, 2, ..., n-1].
```

As an example, if `N=8` and `n=2`, we straightforwardly have `ngroup(1:length(V),n,1) = c(1,3,5,7)` (odd numbers) and `ngroup(1:length(V),n,0) = c(2,4,6,8)` (even numbers), thus

```
U = paste(V[c(1,3,5,7)], V[c(2,4,6,8)], sep='')
```

so that `U` is the vector ["V[1]V[2]" "V[3]V[4]" "V[5]V[6]" "V[7]V[8]"] symbolically written (concatenate V[1] with V[2], V[3] with V[4], etc.).

Perhaps we could do something with the 'apply' family of functions, but I'm not at-ease in this situation. I thank you very much for your assistance!

Comment: You can use `apply()` on `matrix(V, n)`. something like `apply(matrix(V, n), 1, paste0, collapse='')`

Comment: Hi, with ```apply(t(matrix(V, n)), 1, paste0, collapse='')``` it does work. Thanks!

Comment: try, `apply(matrix(V, n), 2, paste0, collapse='')`

Answer (score 3):

Without loops as requested (`*apply` is a loop):

```
V <- letters[1:24]
n <- 3

foo <- function(V, n) {
  stopifnot(length(V) %% n == 0)
  M <- matrix(V, nrow = n)
  do.call(paste0, asplit(M, 1))
}

foo(V, n)
#[1] "abc" "def" "ghi" "jkl" "mno" "pqr" "stu" "vwx"
```

Comment: This one does significantly reduce time. Impressive. Thank you!

Comment: In your solution `do.call(...)` hides the loop.

Comment: @jogo That's not correct. There is no loop. `do.call(paste0, asplit(M, 1))` is the same as `paste0(asplit(M, 1))[[1]], asplit(M, 1))[[2]], asplit(M, 1))[[3]])` (but only with one call to `asplit` obviously).

Comment: @Roland so functionally you have to do the same as what is done by `*apply()`.

Comment: @jogo I don't understand your last comment. I can only reiterate: the approach shown in my answer does not involve an R level loop.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try

```
sapply(split(V, ceiling(seq_along(V)/n)),paste0, collapse = "")
```

or

```
do.call(paste0,as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,split(V, ceiling(seq_along(V)/n)))))
```

---

**Example**

```
V <- letters[1:24]
n <- 3
```

such that

```
> sapply(split(V, ceiling(seq_along(V)/n)),paste0, collapse = "")
    1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
"abc" "def" "ghi" "jkl" "mno" "pqr" "stu" "vwx"
```